# Nexus/Maven how do you NOT proxy everything through Nexus

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I only want to use Nexus for our projects libraries and not deal with the overhead of resources and proxying every possible repository someone might use. Is this possible and simple to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more than advisable to have a company hosted artifact repository manager. Together with repository groups and some basic routing rules, this will:

- Decrease your external traffic for artifacts.
- Decrease the amount of time required in order to download the artifacts.
- Help you control where artifacts are obtained from.
- Help you control what artifacts end up in your project.
- Allow you to keep working, even if Maven Central is (for whatever reason) down, or you're experiencing Internet issues (or lack a connection to the Internet).
- Provide consistency.

Running an artifact repository manager on your dev machine is actually often a good practice as well.

I'm not quite sure why you're like to not have all the artifacts served through your own repository, if you already have one, as this will benefit you quite a lot.

If your really must use your repository server just for your internal artifacts, then you'll need to add additional `<repository/>` sections to your `pom.xml` files. Instead of doing this, you can simply use your repository manager, use a group repository and define in your `settings.xml` that your company repository is acting as a `<mirrorOf/>` Maven Central.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Oh yes, I knew I would get the lecture/sales pitch why not to do it. Ask, a simple question in search of a simple answer and low behold you get a Java Enterprise mumbo jumbo speech creating another system to manage, to enable another Uber over engineered enterprise solution.  But, seriously thanks!

Comment: Well, as you can see, my answer was very generic and not recommending either artifact repository manager. Nexus is great. I use it and would recommend it. That's not the question, the question is that by trying to avoid using a repository manager as it was intended, you'll be losing out on all the benefits (which are quite a lot longer than the list). I just wanted to let you know this from a Build & Release Engineer's point of view (and I've been dealing with this for about a decade now). Just sayin'... Good luck! :-)

Comment: Carl your answer was excellent and will help many people new to build management, Maven and Nexus.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. If you dont use a settings.xml mirror setting you can add the Nexus repositories to your settings.xml or pom.xml and proceed.

Obviously (for the reasons mentioned above) this is not ideal, but its possible ;-)